# Not able to read localconfig during Bugzilla installation

Tags: linux, shell, bugzilla

I am newbie to testing.
I am trying to install Bugzilla.
when i enter command:

> ./checksetup.pl

It shows following at the end:

> Reading ./localconfig...
>   ./localconfig: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Install/Localconfig.pm line 250,  line 749.

can not understand this
can anyone explain?

Comment: YEs i am running checksetup.pl from Bugzilla director, which means my current account does not has write access to that directory. how i can provide access or check for the account which has access

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla is trying to create a file named localconfig in the current directory, however you don't have access to write to that directory.

Make sure you are running checksetup.pl from the Bugzilla directory (cd /path/to/bugzilla; ./checksetup.pl), and your current account has write access to that directory.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: YEs i am running checksetup.pl from Bugzilla directory

Comment: which means my current account does not has write access to that directory. how i can provide access or check for the account which has access.

Comment: You can always use root the superuser to install anything on linux or install in the directory where the user has access like /home/alok for eg if the user is added by default the home directory of that user is created or else you can give full permission to the directory being root user for bugzilla i.e chmod -R 777 /home/bugzilla for eg.